# weird behavior of jQuery Steps plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery Steps plugin ([LINK HERE](http://www.jquery-steps.com/)). Problem is in one IF statements that returns wizzard to first step (not on step that is currently indexed). All IF statements are working correctly expect this one. That if statemnt is checking if phone number is in correct format:

Here is code:

```
onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {
                            var filter = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                            if (!filter.test($("#email").val())) {
                            $("#emailError").text("e-mail is wrong");
                            return false;
                            }
                            if (!filter.test($("#email2").val())) {
                            $("#email2Error").text("e-mail is wrong");
                            return false;
                            }
                            var newnum = parseInt($("#numppl").val());
                            if(Math.floor(newnum) != newnum && !$.isNumeric(newnum)){
                            $("#numpplError").text("Number error");
                            return false;
                            }
                            if (!($("#numppl").val() >= 1 && $("#numppl").val()<=10)){
                            $("#numpplError").text("Number error");
                            return false;
                            }
                             if ($("#email").val()!=($("#email2").val())){
                             $("#email2Error").text("address don't match");
                             return false;
                             }
                            /*IF Statment bellow is bugged */
                            if ($("#phone").length) {
                             if(!$("#phone").match(/^[+]?([\d]{0,3})?[\(\.\-\s]?([\d]{3})[\)\.\-\s]*([\d]{3})[\.\-\s]?([\d]{4})$/)){
                              $("#phoneError").text("Wrong format");
                                return false;
                             }
                             }
                             return true; 
                             },
```

Answer (score 0):

Make correction in IF Statement in which you commented as bug :

```
       pval = $("#phone").val(); //Store the value of "Phone"
       if (pval.length) {   //Check for non empty
                         if(!pval.match(/^[+]?([\d]{0,3})?[\(\.\-\s]?([\d]{3})[\)\.\-\s]*([\d]{3})[\.\-\s]?([\d]{4})$/))  { // Check format.
                               $("#phoneError").text("Wrong format");
                               return false;
                               }
                         }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#phone").length` isn't same as the length of phone number

inspite of `$("#phone").length` use `($("#phone").val()).length`

similarly inspite of `$("#phone").match(regular Expression)` use

```
($("#phone").val()).match(regular Expression)
```